# Quirky Ruby on Rails Syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Background: Novice rails developer here learning from Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial (https://www.railstutorial.org/) in which you develop a basic twitter-like app with a User model and Post model. The users routes are generated from what I understand is the common method of inserting the following into the routes.rb file:

```
resources :users
```

Question: I don't understand why when you use:

`redirect_to @user`

rails sends that request to UsersController#show, but it does so by calling user_url(@user) via:

```
get "/users/id" => "users#show"
```

Where does the singular ("user") in user_url come from in the code immediately above? I would think user-url should be users_url or users_path (as I see come up in some places). Just trying to figure out where this singular is coded into rails.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's follow some code down the rabbit hole, starting with `redirect_to @user`

`redirect_to` performs a redirect with `location` set to `url_for(@user)` [link](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2090615d39c071c9eb25e715275eb79f3f9b6266/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/redirecting.rb#L69)

```
def redirect_to(options = {}, response_status = {}) #:doc:
  ...
  self.location      = _compute_redirect_to_location(request, options)
  ...
end

def _compute_redirect_to_location(request, options) #:nodoc:
  ...
  else
    url_for(options)
 ...
end
```

So far, so good. `redirect_to` has no say in how the path is determined. Next, let's look at `url_for`. [link](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/9685080a7677abfa5d288a81c3e078368c6bb67c/actionview/lib/action_view/routing_url_for.rb)

```
def url_for(options = nil)
  ...
  else
    ...
    builder = ActionDispatch::Routing::PolymorphicRoutes::HelperMethodBuilder.send(method)
    ...
      builder.handle_model_call(self, options)
    ...
end
```

Looks like `url_for` is in charge of deciding how the url should be built. In this case, it gets sent to HelperMethodBuilder. [link](https://github.com/rails/docrails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb)

```
   def handle_model_call(target, model)
      method, args = handle_model model
      target.send(method, *args)
   end

   def handle_model(record)
      ...
      named_route = if model.persisted?
                      ...
                      get_method_for_string model.model_name.singular_route_key
                    ...
      [named_route, args]
   end

   def get_method_for_string(str)
     "#{prefix}#{str}_#{suffix}"
   end
```

There we go. `handle_model` gets the the (persisted) record's `model_name`, which returns an `ActiveModel::Name` object, and gets the `singular_route_key` from it.

```
pry(main)> User.first.model_name.singular_route_key  
=> "user"
```

`get_method_for_string` uses the  `singular_route_key` to complete the helper method to call. I will leave the logic to derive `"prefix"`/`"suffix"` as an academic exercise, but it should return `"user_path"`.

So, to answer the question, the singular form is coded into ActiveModel::Name and HelperMethodBuilder. Hope that helps!

Comment: And vualá! Thank you, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to rails.

If you view all of your routes, you might notice why this happens straight away.  But since devise adds lots of extra routes that might be confusing too.

Rail's routing uses the notion of plural and singlar models.

So lets say you have A user, the path is singluar --  `user_path(@user)` - and the url for this will be `/users/1`.

If you want to view a collection of ALL users, the path is plural -- `users_path` -- and the URL for this will be `/users`

The same goes for all routes related to that user.  When you're talking about actions that only affect a single object the route is singular, and actions that affect multiple objects are plural.  A long read but because it dictates how actions are resolved, an excellent resource is: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: So I understand where the path `users_path` and the URL `/users` comes from because when I run `rake routes` I see the several routes generated by `resources : users` such as `users   GET    /users(.:format)     users#index`. And I see how the URI for this rout is `users`, which all makes sense to me.

But I don't see where in the code the singular of users comes from.

Comment: Its simply a semantic helper to return the correct URL.  Because you're only looking for a single object, the helper is singular.  All of the path helpers are this way and it's not code you'll "see" unless you dig into the rails core.

Comment: Okay so it's within the rails core and I won't see it explicitly in any of the routes, that's what I wanted to know. Thank you.